# FirebaseUI RecyclerView how to add an element to a defined position

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

Following my recent visit to Firestore I try to use Firebase-UI's RecyclerView but I cannot find a way to add a new element to a certain position.

Here's how I did with a basic RecyclerView:

```
mDataset.add(position,elenmet);
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I found this method `mRecyclerView.addView(view, position);` but I do not have a view, only of my element which is an object of the same type as the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. To add an element to a specific position and to notify the adapter, this line of code is not needed at all. To solve this, just remove it from your code. The adapter is already notified using:

```
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
```

Comment: You did not understand my problem, I want to add an item with the Firebase-UI's RecyclerView, notify adapter is the second part. With Firebase-UI's RecyclerView I do not have a dataset

Comment: Have you first added it to the database?

Comment: Yes he is already in the database. The thing is that it was already showing but the user to decide to delete it via a button but when he click on the button I just delete the item from the list via `mRecyclerView.removeViewAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());` and the user to 10 sec for click on another button to cancel the deletion if at the end of these seconds it has not canceled it is at that moment that it is deleted from the database but if it clicked I would like to redisplay it (it is always in the database since it has not been deleted)

Comment: A better way would be only to hide that view. If the user doesn't do anything at the end of those 10 second then just delete the record from the database otherwise restore the view, right?